# Conditional Perl Shebang?

Tags: perl

I have a situation where I need to detect if a particular perl executable, `/usr/goofy/bin/perl` exists and if so use it to run the Perl script otherwise use `/usr/bin/perl`.

I have been struggling with this small POC script, called `perlshebang.pl`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
perls="/usr/goofy/bin/perl /usr/bin/perl"
for pl_exec in $perls
do
    if [ -x $pl_exec ]; then
        exec "$pl_exec -w -S \"$0\" ${1+\"$@\"}"
    fi
done

print "[$^X] Whoop!\n";
```

When I run this on a system that does not have `/usr/goofy/bin/perl` I get this error message:

```
./perlshebang.pl: 6: exec: /usr/bin/perl -w -S "./perlshebang.pl" : not found
```

And when I run it on a system that does have `/usr/goofy/bin/perl` I get a similuar error message:

```
./perlshebang.pl: line 6: /usr/goofy/bin/perl -w -S "./perlshebang.pl" : No such file or directory
```

I think I am close but cannot figure out why I am getting these error messages.

Thanks!

Comment: The correct way to handle this would be to rely on standard precedence rules in the path. The stuff at the beginning of `PATH` will be searched first.

Comment: yes that would be nice.  But I do not have control over the PATH on all the systems my script will have to run on.

Comment: That's even worse. If this is something you're distributing, and a certain version or flavor of Perl is required, then you make it a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A co-worker of mine came up with this.  I am not sure I fully understand it but it seems to work fine:

```
#!/bin/sh
#! -*-perl-*- 
eval ' if test -x /usr/goofy/bin/perl ; then
    exec /usr/goofy/bin/perl -x -S $0 ${1+"$@"};
elif test -x /usr/bin/perl ; then 
    exec /usr/bin/perl -x -S $0 ${1+"$@"};
fi '
if $running_under_some_shell;


use strict; 
use warnings; 
print "hello world\n"; # if $foo; 
printf("running %s v(%vd)\n", $^X, $^V);

__END__

unpod like docs. 
See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html
```

Comment: since you're using perl's `-x` command line switch, you can move the 2nd `#!` line down to just before the `use strict` and you won't have to "hide" your shell scripting from perl with the `if $running_under_some_shell` line...

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, "Why am I getting these error messages?", the problem is your `exec` line:

```
exec "/path/to/cmd arg arg"
# This will attempt to execute a file named "cmd arg arg"
# (with spaces in name) in directory /path/to/
```

Contrast that with

```
exec /path/to/cmd arg arg
# This will attempt to execute a file named "cmd" in directory
# /path/to/, with arguments "arg" and "arg"
```

So, that is why the shell complains that it cannot find your executable.  You don't have a file named `perl -w -s "perlshebang.pl"`, neither under `/usr/bin/` nor under `/usr/goofy/bin/`.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a little ugly to me if you are *releasing* software that uses this hack

If you have no other choice, then I suggest you make sure there is *always* a `/usr/goofy/bin/perl`, and use the shebang line

```
#!/usr/goofy/bin/perl
```

on all your scripts.

For those systems where you want to use the system perl, just make `/usr/goofy/bin/perl` a symlink to `/usr/bin/perl`

Comment: I am going with this but I'll have to declare it as a "workaround" to my bosses.

Comment: @RedCricket: The workaround is the policy of sometimes keeping a custom perl build in a user directory. Your application should go in `/opt` together with everything it needs to function. If your question is answered then please mark one of the answers as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can run the idea out of a Perl script running `/usr/bin/perl`. Use the shebang line with the 'goofy perl' in your script that should run. Then run the following wrapper, followed by the normal invocation of the script (its name and arguments).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

exec "@ARGV";
exec "/usr/bin/perl @ARGV";

print STDERR "Couldn't execute either.\n";
```

Let's call the above `pick_perl.pl`, and your script is `script.pl`. Run it all as

```
pick_perl.pl script.pl args-for-script
```

---

The `exec` replaces the running program altogether with the one it executes, ie. it loads the new program. Thus your script runs with its own shebang. If that failes `exec` returns quietly (with false) and the next statement is executed so the other Perl runs the script (overriding the shebang). This happens if script's shebang fails, but also if the first `exec` fails to execute for any reason.

If you wish/need to run checks then put `exec` in a full `if` block. One can also interrogate the 'goofy_perl' file further if `-e` isn't assuring enough.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$system_perl = "/usr/bin/perl";
$goofy_perl  = "/usr/goofy/bin/perl";

# Your 'goofy_perl' script with its arguments
@script_cmd = @ARGV;

if (-x $goofy_perl) {  exec "@script_cmd" }

exec "$system_perl @script_cmd";
```

The `@script_cmd` has the full command line for your script (which has 'goofy_perl' shebang).

Comment: I seem to be getting stuck in a recursion loop.

Comment: @RedCricket  I don't know whether this is still of interest to you, but I realize I may have not responded -- in the first version I was not clear about how to run this short wrapper.  Now it should be clear, and it has to work. Apologies if this comment is excessive.